# Why can't I say <iframe /> and be done with it?

Tags: xml, xhtml

I thought that in XML you could have a tag with opening and closing tags, and then if you didn't need the closing tag, you could just use a tag with a slash at the end of it.

```
<!-- needs text/elements within tag so opening and closing tag are needed -->
<myTag>Text here</myTag>
<!-- doesn't need text/elements so doesn't have closing tag -->
<myTag />
```

I'm guessing that this is just because that's whatever everyone decided was best and this is now just a XHTML peculiarity, but why? Is there a technical reason for this that I don't know about?

Thanks!

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-tags-work) has some relevant info.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because the **[XHTML DTD](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/dtds.html)** says so :)

Only these elements are allowed to be empty:

- area
- base
- br
- col
- hr
- img
- input
- link
- meta
- param

For example `link` is declared as:

```
<!ELEMENT link EMPTY>
```

whereas `script` and `iframe` are declared as:

```
<!ELEMENT script (#PCDATA)>
```

and

```
<!ELEMENT iframe %Flow;>
<!ENTITY % Flow "(#PCDATA | %block; | form | %inline; | %misc;)*">
...
```

Answer (score 1):

If browsers treated XHTML as XML, you would be right. But they treat it as HTML, where the rules are different.

Answer (score 0):

It's simply the rules of HTML. Some elements, like the `script` and `iframe` tags always have a closing tag.

This is a bit of a quirk, as it contradicts how XML works, where a self closing tag is exactly the same thing as an empty tag.